# Taiko/Gauge - The Header Basic Authorization is getting mixed with the form Login

Tags: javascript, automation, basic-authentication, gauge, exchange-basicauth

In Taiko/Gauge Framework, we try to implement Basic Authorization with Base64 encoding method to launch a website. It works fine. But, when we try to login as a user which is a form on the application flow, it is not getting logged in. When we do it manually, there is no issue.

The code is something like this.

```
goto(url,{headers:{'Authorization':'Basic '}}) => This works well.
```

On the login page, I need to give the user name (EmailID) and password as below:

```
await write("EmailID", into(textBox{id:"IDValueEmail"}));
await write("Password", into(textBox{id:"IDValuePassword"}));
await evaluate($(customelocatorSignin), ele => ele.click());
```

I have two questions:

How to overwrite the password set for the URL using headers?
I am not able to login with the particular valid credentials as a user on the login page. It just stays on the same page without throwing any error. How to resolve this issue.